# How to redirect the telnet console logs to a file Linux

Tags: linux, shell, tcl

I want to redirect the telnet console logs to a file in Linux.

For example:

```
telnet $someIp > someFile
#ls
#exit
```

I want the console logs to be saved in the filename `someFile`. I am using `tcl` for automating this. As of now, I am doing `spawn telnet $someIp` in `tcl`.

This will not capture the console logs and save it to a file.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expect has a programmatic means to start and stop recording (or logginig). Given a file name argument, the `log_file` command opens the file and begins recording to it. If a log file is already open, the old file is closed first.

Recording is done by appending to the file, so if anything has previously been stored in the file, it remains. To start over, use the `-noappend` flag.

**You can save space by turning off logging when it is not necessary. This is accomplished by calling `log_file` with no arguments.** For example, the following fragment starts recording, does some I/O, stops recording, does some more I/O, and then starts recording again.

```
expect . . . ; send
# start recording
log_file telnetlog
expect . . . ; send
# stop recording
log_file
expect . . . ; send
# start recording
log_file telnetlog
expect . . . ; send
```

By default, `log_file` records only what the user sees. If the `log_user` command has been invoked to suppress output from a spawned program, the suppressed output is not recorded by log_file since the user is not seeing it either. The `log_file` can record the suppressed output by using the `-a` flag (for "all output").

```
log_file -a log
```

As before, this logging can be disabled by issuing log_file with no arguments. To return to logging just what the user sees, invoke log_file without the -a.

```
log_file -a log
expect . . . ; send . . .
log_file log
```

Reference : [Exploring Expect](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do)

Answer (score 26):

You can do it by using the `tee` command:

```
telnet $someIp | tee -a -i someFile
```

Comment: Thanks.It worked. But i could see some junk characters getting displayed like ^[[1;34m. Any idea how to remove this?

Comment: @Saran Those are just codes for rendering colors.  Refer to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58982/disable-colours-on-terminal-and-ssh on how to get rid of them

Comment: Exactly what I needed - damn telnet in 2020 and those ISP router/modems who still use telnet and not SSH :)

Comment: this is useful, I'm going to backup memcached data