# TCL script only saves the bottom half of the output

Tags: bash, tcl, buffer, expect, unset

I have  script that logs into devices and runs a show command. 
I then set this output to a variable:

```
set output $expect_out(buffer)
```

and then print the variable to a file:

```
puts $fileId $output
```

When the script is run, I can see the whole output being generated, however in the file, only the bottom half of the output is saved.

This is probably because the buffer is reaching its limit. This show command is running right after another lengthy show command.

I tried using `unset expect_out(buffer)` but this still does not make a difference.

I also tried this solution http://wiki.tcl.tk/2958 and it still did not work (returns an error)
How can I get the script to store all of the output?

Answer (score 1):

I see in the expect man page that the pattern `full_buffer` will match when the size of the buffer reaches `match_max` bytes, so you can do something like:

```
match_max 16000
# ...
expect {
    full_buffer {
        puts $fileid $expect_out(buffer)
        exp_continue
    }
    "whatever you are currently expecting"
}
puts $fileid $expect_out(buffer)
```

Comment: This is risky, as I am not too sure how large an output can be. It will depend on the device. Is there a way to dynamically allocate the max buffersize depending on the output?

Comment: Does your computer have less than 16kb of memory? My code should write to the file in 16kb chunks

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the `log_file` to make it simple. You can control when to save and when to stop logging.

Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28293016/974155) to know about the same.

Comment: When I do this, it works, but only for the first command. Is there an issue with opening a log file, closing it, and then opening another different log file? it seems like after the first log_file has been created, the script just ends

Comment: I hope you have asked new question about it in http://stackoverflow.com/q/28796121/974155. Let me check it in there.